# Getting Row Count With for-loop

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I need a function that finds all the lines that end with "end". Then, I need to count how many lines all together and use print to print out the number.

This is my code below:

```
count = 0

for line in open("jane_eyre.txt"):
    line_strip = line.rstrip()
    if line_strip.endswith(" end"):    
        lines = line_strip
        count += 1
        print("There are", count, "lines that end in 'end'.")
```

Expected Result:

```
There are 4 lines that end in 'end'.
```

My Current Result:

```
There are 1 lines that end in 'end'.
There are 2 lines that end in 'end'.
There are 3 lines that end in 'end'.
There are 4 lines that end in 'end'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a miss-indentation:

```
count = 0

for line in open("jane_eyre.txt"):
    line_strip = line.rstrip()
    if line_strip.endswith(" end"):    
        lines = line_strip
        count += 1
print("There are", count, "lines that end in 'end'.") # < look at now and before and compare.
```

Comment: Thank you. I can see where is my mistake now!

Answer (score 1):

Just move the `print` to end of the loop.

```
count = 0
for line in open("jane_eyre.txt"):
   line_strip = line.rstrip()
   if line_strip.endswith(" end"):    
       lines = line_strip
       count += 1
print("There are", count, "lines that end in 'end'.")
```

Comment: I see, thank you! I shouldn't put that under the for-loop!

Comment: @hiro Let me explain. Im using the site from mobile. So to avoid typing whole thing again, I copy-pasted OP code and moved print to outside of loop. I know that while pasting the code, there are some leading spaces, but my sole aim was to make the OP know his indentation mistake. Next, after uploading my answer only, SO showed that there was an an answer. (Mathematically, it took me 2 minute to type the answe). Nothing wrong I hope... ^^